# cpan : command not found on Redhat 9

Tags: perl, redhat, cpan

I want to compile Qt5 on RedHat 9, and when I run the ./configure command, I get the following message:

> Can't locate English.pm in @INC (you may need to install the English
> module) (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/5.32
> /usr/local/share/perl5/5.32 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
> /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5) at
> /home/nekcorp/Downloads/qt5/qtbase/bin/syncqt.pl line 55. BEGIN
> failed--compilation aborted at
> /home/user/Downloads/qt5/qtbase/bin/syncqt.pl line 55.

So, I tried to install English.pm with cpan, but when I run the cpan command, I get the message:

> command not found.

I then tried to install it with ***yum install
perl-CPAN***, but I received the following message:

> No match for argument: perl-CPAN  Error: Unable to find a match:
> perl-CPAN.

Normally, isn't cpan included with perl during its installation?

Note: I have Perl version 5, version 32, subversion 1 (v5.32.1) installed on RedHat 9.2.

Comment: Is there not an rpm English module?  I find this on our RedHat-based system: `perl-English-1.11-480.el9.noarch`.  But at any rate, you should also have a cpan or a variant of it (like cpanm),  for the future anyway.  On our system: `perl-CPAN-2.29-3.el9.noarch`, and a couple of `perl-CPAN-Meta*` and a few other `perl-CPAN-*` packages.  Perhaps you don't have the right repositories set up with your rpm?

Comment: "_Normally, isn't cpan included with perl during its installation?_" -- I would imagine so. But installation images can be prepared in custom ways

Comment: "_command not found_"  -- Also, check paths -- perhaps `cpan` is somewhere there?

Comment: I don't have a RedHat nearby, but as I recall, they incorrectly package perl so that there are several different things you have to install to get the full installation of standard perl. You might have already tried this, but look at the results of `yum list "perl-*"` to see what the names might be.

Comment: I recall a `perl-core` module they separated out for some reason with a lot of stock packages in it.

Comment: @briandfoy When I use the command yum list perl-cp*, I found perl-CPAN-02Packages-Search.noarch perl-CPAN-02Packages-Search-tests.noarch  perl-CPAN-Changes.noarch perl-CPAN-Common-Index.noarch perl-Cpanel-JSON-XS.x86_64. So, How can I install it?

Comment: Considering one is connected and subscribed correctly to `rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms`, the command `dnf provides perl-CPAN` will result into an output of `perl-CPAN-2.29-3.el9.noarch : Query, download and build perl modules from CPAN sites
Repo        : rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms
Matched from:
Provide    : perl-CPAN = 2.29-3.el9`

Comment: @mnekkach: Those packages you've found won't contain what you're looking for. They are completely separate (and rather obscure) modules.

Comment: @mnekkach  I wrote in the very first comment above what the RHEL9 packages are for what you are asking.  Can download them from `pkgs.org` for example and install them manually.  But then the question is, what kind of an installation package/image has been used to put Perl on your system?  (Why do you not have these already?)  Do you know this -- did you install Perl yourself? How did you do that? Or is this at work or so?

Comment: @zdim I tried to install it from the perl-CPAN-2.29-2.el9.noarch.rpm file using the command sudo rpm -ivh perl-CPAN-2.29-2.el9.noarch.rpm, but there are missing dependencies. I didn't install Perl myself; it was already installed. The dependencies are as follows:error: Failed dependencies:
    perl is needed by perl-CPAN-2.29-2.el9.noarch
    perl(Archive::Tar) >= 1.50 is needed by perl-CPAN-2.29-2.el9.noarch
    perl(Archive::Zip) is needed by perl-CPAN-2.29-2.el9.noarch
    perl(CPAN::Meta) >= 2.110350 is needed by perl-CPAN-2.29-2.el9.noarch

Comment: OK.  Could let it install the dependencies as well (if repositories are set), and better use `dnf` (well, or `yum`) than vanilla `rpm`.  But I'm not sure how good your Perl installation is -- [English](https://perldoc.perl.org/English) is a core module and so is [Archive::Tar](https://perldoc.perl.org/Archive::Tar), and so should be [cpan](https://perldoc.perl.org/cpan).   So why aren't they there?  List all perl rpm's (`rpm -qa | grep perl` will give a few extras, or use `...| grep '^perl'`) and see what's there.  Should be hundreds of packages

Comment: I forget what that silly "_Failed dependencies: perl is needed by ..._" message means, but it could be that your Perl installation, or some component of it (perhaps repositories?), is messed up.   Have you run any Perl programs?

Comment: I solved my problem by reinstalling Perl using Perlbrew.

Comment: "_solved my problem by reinstalling Perl_"  -- yay, and thanks for updating here.  Btw, perlbrew is super useful as one can maintain multiple independent Perls with it.  Great for testing things out etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to a Centos/RHEL 9 box to try this out on, but on Centos 8 the fix to get a complete Perl installation was always:

```
sudo yum install perl-core
```

Comment: same error message : No match for argument: perl-core

Error: Unable to find a match: perl-core

Comment: @mnekkach: Then I don't know what else to suggest. I would spin up a Centos 9 Docker container to try it out, but Centos seem to have stopped making containers available.

Comment: CentOS has moved on, to stream only.  Now there's Rocky Linux and AlmaLinux which are meant to be binary compatible w/ RHEL (and Rocky uses identical sources, supposedly)

Comment: Here's [docker images](https://hub.docker.com/search?image_filter=official&q=rocky) for Rocky Linux